# Proving that a family of sets is a free filter

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, set-theory, filters

> We say that a subset $A$ of $\mathbb{N}$ has density if the limit
> $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{|A \cap [n]|}{n}$$  exists (where $[n] = \{1,2,\dots,n\}$).
>
> Prove that the family $\mathcal{F}$ of subsets of $\mathbb{N}$
> with density equal to $1$ is a free filter on $\mathbb{N}$.

**My proof:** It's easy to verify that $\emptyset \notin \mathcal{F}$ and that if $F\subseteq G \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ and $F \in \mathcal{F}$ then $G\in \mathcal{F}$. To show that if $F, G \in \mathcal{F}$ then $F\cap G \in \mathcal{F}$ notice that
$$|F \cap G \cap [n]| \geq |F \cap [n]| + |G \cap [n]| - n$$
Dividing the above inequality by $n$ and taking limits as $n\to \infty$ we are done.
To prove that $\mathcal{F}$ is free notice that $S_k = \mathbb{N} \setminus \{k\} \in \mathcal{F}$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and since $\bigcap_k S_k = \emptyset$ we get that $\mathcal{F}$ is a free filter.

Is this proof correct? If not, how should I approach this problem? Thanks.

Comment: The proof is correct, but there is no reason to state that $\emptyset \notin \mathcal{F}$. That has nothing to do with whether it's a filter. I think what you meant to do was show that $\mathcal{F}$ is not empty - you probably just got confused on that requirement. You showed that $\mathcal{F}$ is not empty by coming up with the $S_k$.

Comment: @MarkSaving That's actually the definition given in my topology class so that's why I included it. I think it makes sense because if $\emptyset \in \mathcal{F}$ then every set belongs in $\mathcal{F}$ so $\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{P}(X)$.

Comment: It's almost certainly a typo - the intent was probably $\emptyset \neq \mathcal{F}$. If the relevant partial order isn't a power set, why would it even be relevant whether $\emptyset \in \mathcal{F}$? That would have nothing at all to do with the structure of the partial order.

Comment: @MarkSaving I doubt that it's a typo since non-empty is also stated in the definition. Also, this definition appears in lecture notes by two different professors. I think they just don't consider the trivial filter as a filter so that's why they added that requirement.

Comment: I like your inequality for a very simple method for showing $F\cup G\in\mathcal F.$ Well done.

Comment: @mark-saving The OP is using the definition of a [filter in topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filters_in_topology), not the definition of a [filter in a poset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_(mathematics)).

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Thank you!